# How to get the sum of two rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, insert

I have two rows in a table. I want to add in a third row which holds the total value.

My table is

```
SELECT 
CONTROLLED_PERCENTAGE, EL_CLIENT_ID, ID, 
   PERC_ADJ_UNITS_RECEIVED, PHY_DIG_OR_TOTAL, RECORDING_ID, 
   SUM_UNITS_RECEIVED, UNIT_TYPE
FROM EL_CLIENT_REC_UNITS;
```

I will have the `EL_CLIENT_ID`, `UNIT_TYPE`, `PHY_DIG_OR_TOTAL` will be 'PHY' or 'DIG' and I am looking to get the total. I want to add up the two record's `SUM_UNITS_RECEIVED` and `PERC_UNITS_RECEIVED` where the `UNIT_TYPES`, `EL_CLIENT_ID` and `RECORDING_ID`s are the same. I then want to insert this as a new row with the same `UNIT_TYPE`, `RECORDING_ID` but this time have `PHY_DIG_OR_TOTAL` set to 'TOTAL';

Comment: :Can you please share some data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT 
    ID, 
    EL_CLIENT_ID, 
    RECORDING_ID, 
    UNIT_TYPE,
    PHY_DIG_OR_TOTAL, 
    CONTROLLED_PERCENTAGE, 
    SUM_UNITS_RECEIVED, 
    PERC_ADJ_UNITS_RECEIVED
FROM EL_CLIENT_REC_UNITS

UNION ALL -- concatenate sets

SELECT 
    NULL                         AS ID, -- No ID for this row
    EL_CLIENT_ID                 AS EL_CLIENT_ID, 
    RECORDING_ID                 AS RECORDING_ID, 
    UNIT_TYPE                    AS UNIT_TYPE, 
    'TOTAL'                      AS PHY_DIG_OR_TOTAL, 
    AVG(CONTROLLED_PERCENTAGE)   AS CONTROLLED_PERCENTAGE,  -- I don't know what to do with that
    SUM(PERC_ADJ_UNITS_RECEIVED) AS PERC_ADJ_UNITS_RECEIVED,
    SUM(SUM_UNITS_RECEIVED)      AS SUM_UNITS_RECEIVED
FROM EL_CLIENT_REC_UNITS
GROUP BY UNIT_TYPE, EL_CLIENT_ID, RECORDING_ID;
```

Try to google for `GROUP BY` SQL statement to learn more about this statement.